# Spree product subscription customization

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

How can I customise my spree application to have a subscription page like this http://lindseybradford.github.io/occr-fed/dist/subscriptions.html?

I'm using [spree account recurring](https://github.com/vinsol/spree-account-recurring) gem to set recurring plans on stripe.

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to change business logics in spree account recurring gem?
If don't need to change business logic, you can only customize views template.
See [structure of views directory of spree account recurring gem](https://github.com/vinsol/spree-account-recurring/tree/master/app/views) , and make same directory in your rails project, and customize views that you want to.

Comment: Do you think I need to customize logic?

Comment: No, I don't understand exactly what you want to customize.